# Implementing `pure` in ZipList

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative) presents this problem:

> Determine the correct definition of pure for the ZipList instance of Applicative—there is only one 
>   implementation that satisfies the law relating pure and (<*>).

I wasn't sure how to solve it directly, so I tested it out in `ghci`:

```
ghci> pure 5 :: ZipList Int
ZipList {getZipList = [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5, ...
```

where `...` means endless `5`'s.

Why is it implemented in such a way - to produce a list without end?

Comment: have you read  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors#ZipLists ?

Comment: thanks, `ymonad`. Great link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take the identity law for Applicative Functors

```
pure id <*> v = v                            -- Identity
```

In the context of a ZipList, we generate the output by applying each function on the left of `<*>` by its corresponding value on the right side....

```
ZipList [f1, f2, f3, ....] <*> ZipList [v1, v2, v3, ....] = 
       ZipList [f1 v1, f2 v2, f3 v3, ....]
```

so, therefore, to get `v` back, we need each function on the left to be `id`.

```
pure id = [id, id, id, ....]
```

If the left side were a single function `[id]`, the right side would be just one item long.